# Lazy loading hibernate, the correct way and some doubts

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I'm wondering why there is some differences between this 2 approach on lazy loading ('cause i was expected the same result), both approach are with lazy=true and fetch="select"

**Approach number 1**

```
Session miasession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

Invoice i = (Invoice) miasession.get(Invoice.class, id);    

//the Subject entity is Many to One relation
model.addAttribute("subject", i.getSubject());
```

in this approach i get an error when i try to access to "subject" and the error is "org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session" (this is the stack trace https://pastebin.com/3fdDKCV0 )

**Approach number 2**

```
Session miasession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

Invoice i = (Invoice) miasession.get(Invoice.class, id);            

Subject s = (Subject) miasession.get(Subject.class, i.getSubject().getId());

//the Subject entity is Many to One relation
model.addAttribute("subject", s);
```

this one works, but i don't know exactly why the previous approach does not work

PS: this is a bit of pseudo code, the transaction are handled outside this method, i reported just some piece of code to show the problem :)

Comment: in the first approach, does `miasession` still available when calling `getSubject` ?

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul yes it is available

Comment: from the stacktrace the exception doesn't occur, at this point, on `getSubject` but on `getSurname`

Comment: yes, it occur on getSurname but why in the approach number 2 does not occur? 
seems to be that, in the first approach, i need to access 1 random properties of getSubject() to have all other properties available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to get the error in first approach, you could use something like this:

```
Session miasession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

Invoice i = (Invoice) miasession.get(Invoice.class, id); 

// load the collection before session is closed
model.addAttribute("subject", Hibernate.initialize(i.getSubject()));
```

Another way to solve lazy problems is to use OpenSessionInViewFilter in your web.xml

Comment: the use of Hibernate.initialize solved my problem :) thanks a lot Pierpaolo. So the reason behind this is that, in the lazy loading, i need to tell hibernate what object i need to initialize, and my approach number 2 is nothing else that a simple work around to that isn't it?

Comment: just one little edit on the code.. Hibernate.inizialize does not have a return type so first you need to call Hibernate.initialize(i.getSubject()) and after that model.addAttribute("subject", i.getSubject());